# Why are the output of the two tikz code segments inconsistent?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why is the graph drawn by the first code good, while the second code looks not good? In in the first one I use `\the\numexpr  \relax`, and in the second code I use `\tikzmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5} {
  %\node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,fill=blue!20] (\i) at (
  % \i*360/5:1cm ) {$\i$};
  \node[draw,circle,minimum size=0.5cm,fill=blue!20] (\i) at ({
    72*(\i-1)}:1cm) {$\i$};}
 \foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5} {     
 \ifthenelse{\i<5}{ \draw (\i) -- ( \the\numexpr \i+1  \relax );}{ \draw (\i) 
 -- (1);}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5} {
  \node[draw,circle,minimum size=0.5cm,fill=blue!20] (\i) at (72*\i-36:1cm) 
  {$\i$};};
  \foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5} {
   \tikzmath{\j=\i+1;}
     \ifthenelse{\i<5}{ \draw (\i) -- ( \j );}{ \draw 
     (\i)  -- (1);}
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My expectation is that the two outputs should be consistent.

Comment: Try printing out value of j. It is 2.0 i.e. node 2, anchor 0...

Comment: @user202729 Thanks. By the way, what command did you use to make the screen print the value \j? There is nothing by `print{\j};`.

Comment: Options are `\show\j`, `\typeout{\j}`, or `\showtokens\expandafter{\j}`, that prints to the command-line. They all do slightly different things, documentation are in TeXbook/LaTeX reference manual/e-TeX manual.